# Add Metadata To Impulse Responses

Tags: impulse, response, metadata, altiverb

Last night I recorded an impulse response of my building's parking garage with fairly decent results. After importing into Altiverb 7, I couldn't figure out how to add photos or other metadata to the user created IR. Also, I recorded the sine sweep at a couple of different distances from the speaker, so I'd like to combine the two impulse responses into a single user entry, similar to the pre-loaded Altiverb responses that have different mic options.

Comment: Paul - did you ever find a solution? I'm currently working with some of my own IRs and having the same questions.

Comment: Me to, pls share if its founded:)

Comment: Are you talking about text information for Altiverb to display? Or embedding data into the audio files?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got around to creating IRs with 7 yet, but the IRs I created with 6 (with pictures) transferred just fine. Essentially, you just put pictures in a folder with the IRs:


"---|" = Folder


---| My IR

------ My IR.jpg

------| My IR Audio

--------- My IR Stereo.sd2

--------- My IR Mono.sd2

Structuring your IRs/images in folders like this should work. I'm not sure about adding any other kind of data.